# VBA - Merge 3 excel workbooks after filtering for by current date

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I originally posted a question to **merge 3 workbooks** but received nothing but criticism for posting the question.

Nevertheless, I have found the solution to my problem and I am posting it here *ALONG* with my original query for future references.

**Scenario**:

1) Everyday there are **3 csv** files exported; Each of them come from the **3 tools** that manage employee records

2) These **3 csv** files contain the **TERMINATIONS** of users who's access need to be revoked **on that day**

3) The **csv** files are named:

- **Date_Terminations**
- **Date_Terminations_Non_HR**
- **Date_Terminations_Tool**

I have already got the script that copies these files into a new folder and renames them without the date:

- **Terminations**
- **Terminations Non HR**
- **Terminations Tool**

4) Each **csv** file contains the records for employees who's access needed to be revoked for the past **6 months**; The first thing I need to do is **sort/filter the current days date** to the top of the worksheet

5) Then I need to **copy the rows that contain the current date into** the **Terminations Template** file

In a nutshell, I require code that will identify the columns in each workbook by the current day and copy those adjacent rows to the **Terminations_Template** workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

This is my process from start to finish:

1) **3 csv exports** are extracted into

*{directory path}* - with the following filenames:

**{Date}_Daily_Terminations**

**{Date}_Daily_Terminations_NON_HR**

**{Date}_Daily_Terminations_TOOL**

2) I run a script that:

- Converts the **csv** files **into xlsx** files and **delete's** the **csv** copies
- Renames the **3 xlsx files** to

  **Daily Terminations**

  **Daily Terminations NON HR**

  **Daily Terminations TOOL**
- Opens the **Terminations Template xlsm** file that contains **4 sheets** named:

  *Consolidated*

  *Daily Terminations*

  *Daily Terminations NON HR*

  *Daily Terminations TOOL*

3) I execute a macro that does the following:

- Renames the sheets within the **Daily Terminations; Daily Terminations NON 
  HR; Daily Terminations TOOL** xlsx files to the same name as the file itself

*Code:*

```
    Sub RenameOriginalFilesSheets()

    Const TestMode = True
    Dim WB As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rootpath = "{directory path}"

    aFile = Dir(rootpath & "*.xlsx")
    Do
        Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(rootpath & aFile, False, AddToMRU:=False)

        WB.Sheets(1).Name = Left$(WB.Name, InStrRev(WB.Name, ".") - 1)
        WB.Close True

        aFile = Dir()
        DoEvents
    Loop Until aFile = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

- Copy the data from the **Daily Terminations; Daily Terminations NON HR; Daily Terminations TOOL** workbooks and place it in the corresponding sheets within the **Terminations Template** workbook

*Code:*

```
Sub ImportDataSheets()

    'Initialize Variables
    Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook, xWb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim strDir As String

    'Set workbooks to be used
    Set y = Workbooks("Terminations Template.xlsm")

    'Set workbooks to be used
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("{file path}")

    'Set sheets to be used in each workbook
    Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Daily Terminations Non HR")
    Set ws1 = x.Sheets("Daily Terminations Non HR")

    'Copy sheet and close second workbook
    ws1.Cells.Copy ws2.Cells
    x.Close False

    'Set workbooks to be used
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("{file path}")

    'Set sheets to be used in each workbook
    Set ws1 = x.Sheets("Daily Terminations TOOL")
    Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Daily Terminations TOOL")

    'Copy sheet and close second workbook
    ws1.Cells.Copy ws2.Cells
    x.Close False

    'Set workbooks to be used
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("{file path}")

    'Set sheets to be used in each workbook
    Set ws1 = x.Sheets("Daily Terminations")
    Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Daily Terminations")

    'Copy sheet and close second workbook
    ws1.Cells.Copy ws2.Cells
    x.Close False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    y.Activate

    For Each y In Application.Workbooks
        If Not (y Is Application.ActiveWorkbook) Then
            y.Close
        End If

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

- **Delete** the irrelevant columns in the following sheets:

*Daily Terminations*

*Daily Terminations NON HR*

*Daily Terminations TOOL*

*Code:*

```
Sub DeleteIrrelevantColumns()

    'Initialize variables
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    'Assign worksheets to be used
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Terminations Non HR")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Terminations Tool")
    Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Terminations")

    'Rename headers on all sheets if matched
    For Each wrkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*employeeNumber*", Replacement:="Employee Number", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*ts_employee_end_date*", Replacement:="Employee End Date", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*cn*", Replacement:="Employee Full Name", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="mail", Replacement:="Employee Email", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*ts_business_unit*", Replacement:="Business Unit", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*ts_supervisor_employee_number*", Replacement:="Supervisor Employee Number", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="ts_supervisor_mail", Replacement:="Supervisor Email", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*ts_branch_user*", Replacement:="Branch User", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*branch_user*", Replacement:="Branch User", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*status*", Replacement:="Status", Lookat:=xlWhole
        wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*ts_organization*", Replacement:="Organization", Lookat:=xlWhole
    Next wrkSht

    'Bring ws1 into focus
    ws1.Activate

    With ws1

    For currentColumn = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = ws1.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'Check whether to keep column
        Select Case columnHeading

            Case "Employee Number", "Employee End Date", "Business Unit", "Employee Email", "ts_supervisor_firstname", "ts_supervisor_surname", "Branch User", "Employee Full Name", "Supervisor Employee Number", "Status", "Supervisor Email"

                'Do nothing

            Case Else

                    ws1.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

        End Select
    Next

    End With

    'Bring ws2 into focus
    ws2.Activate

    With ws2

    For currentColumn = ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = ws2.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'Check whether to keep column
        Select Case columnHeading

            Case "Employee Number", "Employee End Date", "Business Unit", "Employee Email", "ts_supervisor_firstname", "ts_supervisor_surname", "Branch User", "Employee Full Name", "Supervisor Employee Number", "Status", "Supervisor Email"

                'Do nothing

            Case Else

                    ws2.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

        End Select
    Next

    End With

    'Bring ws3 into focus
    ws3.Activate

    With ws3

    For currentColumn = ws3.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = ws3.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'Check whether to keep column
        Select Case columnHeading

            Case "Employee Number", "sn", "givenName", "Employee End Date", "Business Unit", "Organization", "Employee Email", "ts_supervisor_last_name", "ts_supervisor_first_name", "Supervisor Employee Number", "Branch User", "Supervisor Email"

                'Do nothing

            Case Else

                    ws3.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

        End Select
    Next

    End With

End Sub
```

- **Concatenate** specific columns to create a new name

*Code:*

```
Sub ConcatenateColumns()

    'Initialize variables
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long

    'Assign worksheets to be used
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Terminations Non HR")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Terminations Tool")
    Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Terminations")

    'Bring ws1 into focus
    ws1.Activate

    With ws1


        'Uses Column A to set the 'lngLastRow' variable
        lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Range to be used for concatenation
        .Range("$M$1").Value = "Supervisor Full Name"
        .Range("M2:M" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=E2 & "" "" & F2"

    End With

    'Bring ws2 into focus
    ws2.Activate

    With ws2

        'Uses Column A to set the 'lngLastRow' variable
        lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Range to be used for concatenation
        .Range("$M$1").Value = "Supervisor Full Name"
        .Range("M2:M" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=E2 & "" "" & F2"

    End With

    'Bring ws3 into focus
    ws3.Activate

    With ws3

        'Uses Column A to set the 'lngLastRow' variable
        lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Range to be used for concatenation
        .Range("$N$1").Value = "Employee Full Name"
        .Range("N2:N" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=C2 & "" "" & B2"

    End With

    With ws3

        'Uses Column A to set the 'lngLastRow' variable
        lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Range to be used for concatenation
        .Range("$O$1").Value = "Supervisor Full Name"
        .Range("O2:O" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=I2 & "" "" & H2"

    End With

End Sub
```

- **Reorders** the columns and again delete the ones not needed after concatenation has been done

*Code:*

```
Sub ReorderColumns()

    'Initialize variables
    Dim arrColOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer
    Dim Found As Range, Counter As Integer
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet

    'Assign worksheets to be used
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Terminations Non HR")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Terminations Tool")
    Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Terminations")

    'Bring ws1 into focus
    ws1.Activate

    'Initialize array for header order
    arrColOrder = Array("Employee Number", "Employee End Date", "Employee Full Name", "Employee Email", "Business Unit", _
                        "Supervisor Employee Number", "Supervisor Full Name", "Supervisor Email", "Branch User", "Status")

    'Copy and Paste Sheet as Values
    ws1.Cells.Copy
    ws1.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With ws1

        'Set counter value
        Counter = 1

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

            Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Found Is Nothing Then

                If Found.Column <> Counter Then

                    Found.EntireColumn.Cut
                    Columns(Counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                End If

                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next ndx

        'Columns to delete after columns have been arranged
        ws1.Range("K:M").EntireColumn.Delete

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End With

    'Bring ws2 into focus
    ws2.Activate

    'Initialize array for header order
    arrColOrder = Array("Employee Number", "Employee End Date", "Employee Full Name", "Employee Email", "Business Unit", _
                        "Supervisor Employee Number", "Supervisor Full Name", "Supervisor Email", "Branch User", "Status")

    'Copy and Paste Sheet as Values
    ws2.Cells.Copy
    ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With ws2

        'Set counter value
        Counter = 1

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

            Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Found Is Nothing Then

                If Found.Column <> Counter Then

                    Found.EntireColumn.Cut
                    Columns(Counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                End If

                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next ndx

        'Columns to delete after columns have been arranged
        ws2.Range("K:M").EntireColumn.Delete

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End With

    'Bring ws3 into focus
    ws3.Activate

    'Initialize array for header order
    arrColOrder = Array("Employee Number", "Employee End Date", "Employee Full Name", "Employee Email", "Business Unit", "Supervisor Employee Number", "Supervisor Full Name", "Supervisor Email", "Branch User", "Organization")

    'Copy and Paste Sheet as Values
    ws3.Cells.Copy
    ws3.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With ws3

        'Set counter value
        Counter = 1

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

            Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Found Is Nothing Then

                If Found.Column <> Counter Then

                    Found.EntireColumn.Cut
                    Columns(Counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                End If

                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next ndx

        'Columns to delete after columns have been arranged
        ws3.Range("K:N").EntireColumn.Delete

        'Insert new column
        ws3.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Insert

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End With

End Sub
```

- **Consolidates* the 3 sheets into one sheets - **Consolidated**

Sub Consolidate()

```
    'Initialize variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    'Assign worksheets to be used
    Set ws = Worksheets("Daily Terminations Non HR")
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Consolidated")

    'Find last row
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy range up to last row
    ws.Range("A2:K" & LastRow).Copy

    'Paste in next empty row
    ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Bring ws1 into focus
    ws1.Activate

    'Assign worksheets to be used
    Set ws = Worksheets("Daily Terminations TOOL")
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Consolidated")

    'Find last row
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy range up to last row
    ws.Range("A2:K" & LastRow).Copy

    'Paste in next empty row
    ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Bring ws1 into focus
    ws1.Activate

    'Assign worksheets to be used
    Set ws = Worksheets("Daily Terminations")
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Consolidated")

    'Find last row
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy range up to last row
    ws.Range("A2:K" & LastRow).Copy

    'Paste in next empty row
    ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Bring ws1 into focus
    ws1.Activate

    'Insert new column
    ws1.Range("B:B").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("B1").Value = "Logon"

    'Bring cell A1 into focus
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

- **Filters** the **Consolidated** sheet by date to show every record **excluding the previous day** - If today is the 3rd, then it will display all records EXCEPT those of the 2nd

*Code*

```
Sub DateFilter()

    'Initialize variables
    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated")
    Dim c As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Current_Date As Date

    'Find the last row with contents
    LastRow = oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With oWS

        'Loop through all celss in column B and change format to date
        For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Cells

            Current_Date = CDate(c)
            c.Value = Current_Date

        Next c

        'Make all cells in column A "General" input
        Columns(1).NumberFormat = "General"

        ' Set the autofilter to display all dates other than yesterdays
        .Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -1, Date)), Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -1, Date))

    End With

End Sub
```

- **Delete the filtered records** to display only the records for the previous day - Essentially deleting only the records that are shown after the filter is applied - This also does not delete the headers

*Code*

```
Sub DeleteVisiibleRows()

    'Initialize variables
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

    'Assign sheet to be used
    Set sh = Sheets("Consolidated")

    With sh

        'Find the last row with data in it
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Use only filtered cells - visible cells as filter is applied; Exclusing headers
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        'Delete visible cells
        rng.EntireRow.Delete

        'Remove filter
        .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: InStrRev(Activewoorkbok.Name,".")-1)   should be  InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name,".")-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here You would like to consolidate Three sheets in to one with date filtered, Please use the below code with changes as per your requirement, here it will consolidate all the files present in the target folder with filtered date.

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
 Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("\\C:\ update the target folder")
 Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
 'Here it will open each and every file in the target folder
 For Each everyObj In filesObj
 Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
 ' To filter date
 x = CLng(Date)
 ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<" & x, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & x - 1
' To copy filtered item in the sheet
ActiveSheet.Range("A:T").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
' Paste it in the Macro sheet's non empty row
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close 
Next
End Sub
```

Thank You 
try to use loops effectively for a robust way